# Why isn't "myObject ??= defaultValue;" possible in C#?

Tags: c#

Why isn't `myObject ??= defaultValue;` possible in C#?

It would be very nice !

Comment: It's not possible because nobody thought of, designed, implemented, tested, documented, and shipped it.

Comment: if you mean: "myObject = trueValue ?? defaultValue;" then it is. Where the ?? operator allows for defaultValue to be assigned if trueValue is null

Comment: @AnthonyPegram and _shipped_.

Comment: @Kaizen, he's looking for a null-coalesce & assignment operator... sort of like `x += 1`.

Comment: Eric Lippert did suggest this feature: [Compound Assignment, Part Two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/01/compound-assignment-part-two.aspx). He was joking.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: We thought of it! But the rest, you're right. Didn't do 'em.

Comment: @Kobi: Though that post was my April Fools joke for this year, the `??=` operator would be the most useful of all the crazy operators I proposed there.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: "...nobody thought of, designed, implemented,..." I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx) by Eric Lippert about why C# doesn't have many "nice-to-have" language features.